# Isn't it a problem that both of these characters died during the trial by combat?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones*, after the second trial by combat requested by the Imp, Prince Oberyn dies at the hand of the Mountain but the Mountain also dies at the hand of Prince Oberyn.

At the end of that trial by combat Tywin Lannister proclaims that the gods have made their will known, but I feel it's much more complicated in this case since both of them died.

It is never explicit in the show that the Mountain dies on the spot but at the very least he is dying very soon (apparently from the poison on Oberyn's blade). In any case, he is dying as a result of that trial by combat.

So I'm just wondering, if the outcome of this trial by combat is considered fairly (a tie), what would be the judgement upon the Imp?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  You seem to be projecting your own opinion (that the result should be "a tie") onto a situation that was resolved differently.  Why is that opinion more correct than the decision of the characters that were present?

Comment: Tywin (for whatever reasons) seems to want to use the excuse to rid himself of his difficult child.  As hand of the king, he can pretty much do as he pleases - so to declare that Oberyn dying shows that Tyrion is guilty seems fairly in-character and who would dare go against that.

Comment: Oberyn clearly died **first**.

Comment: @DavidW Hi and thanks for the comment. It is not my own opinion that they both died as a result of that trial by combat. It is what it is. In Game of Thrones terms, it was the gods' will to have them both dead and so their judgement upon the Imp is not as clear Tywin makes it out to be.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I wasn't aware that in trial by combat it is the first death that determines judgement in case of fighters dying. Do you have a reference to that somewhere?

Comment: I can’t provide a reference which is why I commented instead of answering. That said, Tyrion’s trial itself might be a good reference, since it seems clear to everyone that Tyrion is considered guilty by the rules of trial by combat. No one protests at any time that Tyrion is not guilty since the Mountain also died, which by itself strongly suggests that the champion who dies first loses no matter what happens to the other champion.

Comment: Or simply if the champion of the person under trial dies at all.

Comment: We are (a) trying to ascertain the 'rules' here, and we have nothing to go on other than Tyrion loses and (b) in a hugely unfair and brutal society, it should be no surprise that 'realpolitik' still wins, i.e. the person with power gets his own way.

Comment: It was a clever play for Tyrion to go trial-by-combat, since he had no chance in a normal trial, and if his champion clearly won then he would stand a good chance of surviving. But in any sort of clear loss or ambiguous situation he's not in a good position.

Comment: There's an interesting take on this on Sci-Fi - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58681/96238 - that the 'crown' can never lose, only the defendant.

Comment: I am not sure what are you solving or inventing. Oberyn was dead. The Mountian was not, even long after the combat.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, neither Oberyn nor The Mountain is immortal. Even for a trial by combat that concludes "normally", the so-called winner will still die at some point, but by that time the trial by combat will already have concluded, making the second person's death irrelevant in relation to the trial's outcome. There's no warranty period on that, regardless of whether the second person dies very soon after or years after.

You're trying to change this based on a claim that The Mountain died due to something that Oberyn did. But in doing so, you're glossing over several things:

- At the time that Oberyn was definitely dead, it was not clear that The Mountain had been poisoned.
- It was also not clear that he would die from this poison.
- Where would you draw the line?

  - Suppose the poison does not outright kill him but it damages his heart. Do you now count any future heart failure as being caused by the poison?
  - Suppose it renders him comatose, or in a permanent vegetative state?
  - What if he dies due to a medical mistake, unrelated to the poison itself except that they only took that medical action in an attempt to rescue him from the poison?
  - What if he dies but is resuscitated (e.g. heart massage)? Does that count as death?
  - If the winner of a trial would bleed to death eventually (without poison involved), but a doctor patches them up, does that still count as "it could have killed them" and therefore losing the trial?
- Did he die? After all, he was seen walking around all the way up to the final season of the show!

Game of Thrones quintessentially revolves around the principle of "it's not about what's the truth, it's about what people can argue/believe to be the truth". And simply put, no one would reasonably believe that Oberyn won the trial. Having your head crushed like a ripe tomato will do that to you.

Answer (score 3):

There can never be a tie in trial by combat. The contest ends and judgement rendered when one of the combatants dies or the accuser withdraws their accusations.

The moment Oberyn died first, Tyrion was guilty. It does not matter what happened to Gregor after that.

This was not explicitly established in the show, but some detail was given in *The Hedge Knight*.

> "If Ser Duncan is killed, it is considered that the gods have judged him guilty, and the contest is over. If both of his accusers are slain, or withdraw their accusations, the same is true.

Answer (score 2):

As many users explained in the comments, trial-by-combat was the only chance for Tyrion - if his chosen champion won, he would have a better chance of surviving and being exonarated.

Unfortunately, his champion died first and Tywin took the chance to declare Tyrion guilty - the law is determined by the king and hardly anyone would go against his decision (as Tywin was the Hand of the King and also his grandfather, essentially ruling in King Tommen's behalf). For everyone there it didn't matter if The Mountain died or not, Oberyn had already lost the combat.

Comment: +1.  Someone who does not know GoT might assume Tywin is King from your answer. Tywin is Hand of the King, and grandfather to King Tommen who is a child at this point - and effectively wields the power of the King.

Comment: _"The law is determined by the king"_ is slightly inaccurate in the sense that kings are still expected to play by _some_ rules (such as allowing trial by combat in the first place). If they didn't, then Tywin could've gotten Tommen to bypass Tyrion's trial by combat in the first place. The issue here isn't that the king (or their delegate) can do as they please anyway; it's that the king (or their delegate) had a reasonable enough justification that made it look like the expected rules were being followed, thus not sparking any protest.

Comment: Agreed @Flater but in the event of any ambiguity, it helps to be the local warlord with both money and military power.  In the event that Oberyn had unambiguously won, sure, I think even Tywin would have struggled to overturn the result, which is why Tyrion elected to go down this route.  As you so colorfully state in your answer, I don't think we can argue that happened.